# jQuery loop for setting height for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have a little bit of code that works, but how can I create a loop to apply it to all the `article` elements on the page, resetting the articleheight var each time?

```
function setArticleHeight() {
var wheight = $(window).height();
var articleheight = $('article').height();
        $("article").css("top", -articleheight - wheight);
}

$( document ).ready( setArticleHeight );

window.onresize = setArticleHeight;
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: try using $('article').each() function

Comment: Thanks @Manjunath

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop the elements.

`$.each($('article'), function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).css("top", -articleheight - wheight)
    });`